# Repeated conditional change with sapply or a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, lapply, sapply

I am trying to do a conditional change for a list of 11 columns in R. My conditional is always the same `survey$only0 == 1`. I wrote the following code:

```
survey$w.house[survey$only0 == 1] <- 1
survey$w.inc[survey$only0 == 1] <- 1
survey$w.jobs[survey$only0 == 1] <- 1
survey$w.com[survey$only0 == 1] <- 1
survey$w.edu[survey$only0 == 1] <- 1
survey$w.env[survey$only0 == 1] <- 1
survey$w.health[survey$only0 == 1] <- 1
survey$w.satisf[survey$only0 == 1] <- 1
survey$w.safe[survey$only0 == 1] <- 1
survey$w.bal[survey$only0 == 1] <- 1
survey$w.civic[survey$only0 == 1] <- 1
```

My code works well, but I would like to shorten my code using a `loop` or a function as `sapply` or `lapply`. Does anyone know how to do it ?

Thank you for your help !

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this easily with `lapply` by looping through the columns of interest ('nm1'), and `replace` the values of it to 1 where 'only0' is 1.

```
survey[nm1] <- lapply(survey[nm1], function(x) replace(x, survey$only0==1, 1))
```

Or as @Vlo mentioned the anonymous function call is not needed

```
survey[nm1] <- lapply(survey[nm1], replace, list = survey$only0==1, values=1)
```

where

```
nm1 <- c("w.house", "w.inc", "w.jobs", "w.com", "w.edu", "w.env",
     "w.health", "w.satisf", "w.safe", "w.bal", "w.civic")
```

Comment: Can remove the anonymous function since the indices are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
survey[survey$only0 == 1, cols] <- 1
```

where `cols` are the columns for which you want to check the condition.

```
cols <- c("w.house", "w.inc", "w.jobs", "w.com", "w.edu", "w.env",
            "w.health", "w.satisf", "w.safe", "w.bal", "w.civic")
```